# When are parts of the body personal, and when not?

Tags: personal-pronoun, definite-article

I read the following in a description a patient's visit to the doctor.

> Der Arzt schaut in ihre Augen, ihren Mund, und in die Ohren.

Why ***die** Ohren* but ***ihre** Augen*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is just a variation to reduce repeating words. This also would be correct, but contains 3 times "ihre":

> Der Arzt schaut in ihre Augen, ihren Mund und in ihre Ohren.

Another possibility is this:

> Der Arzt schaut ihr in die Augen, den Mund und die Ohren.

But here the word *ihr* is not a possessive pronoun, but dativus commodi.

Comment: In general, German uses articles instead of possessive pronouns for body parts much more frequently than English. There are a some fixed expressions,"take her by the hand, look her in the eye", but you "look in her ears", never "look her in the ears".